# How to scan the network to find specific peripheral

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ethernet, icmp

I'm creating some small electronic modules for home automation based on Arduino chips, with Ethernet connectivity. I will try to make them get an IP address with DHCP if possible, but I'm also wanting to build a C# application to configure these modules, and I'd like my software to scan the network to auto-detect my modules, as an HP printer driver can auto-detect the printers on the network for instance.

I thought of :

1. getting the computer's IP and Mask to determine the IP set
2. then multi-thread pings or HTTP requests to every IP of the set
3. check the responses and get the mac addresses
4. see if the mac address matches my set
5. do an specific http request to retrieve the "model" of the module, and know how to interact with him

Is this algorithm plausible or do anyone know of a more efficient way ? Like broadcasting requests on the broadcast address and see what gets back ? Any samples or ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Totally plausible. Direct low-level access to put arp requests out and get the arp-table back is little tricky, but there are several questions here on the site. 
Be advised that a device does not have to answer to ping to be able to function on the network. Check the documentation on the chips you use.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to discover over the same network segment, I would actually suggest using a broadcast message instead (UDP). of course you will have to develop the side on the device to respond to that broadcast and listen to those responses. once you get a response, you can start a direct communication to the device using your preferred method.